# scala: recursive function composition

Tags: scala, function

I am trying to stress test scala function composition functionality.
Specifically I trying to define recursive function composition.
So the question is it possible to do in current implementation and if it is, how can I do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def f(x: Int) = {
  println("First ..")
  x + x / 2
}

def g(x: Int) = {
  println("Second ..")
  x * x
}

// this will work as expected
val z = f _ compose g _ 

// will not compile: error => recursive value r needs type
// val r = f _ compose r _ 

val t = z(5)

print(t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to compile or run?

In runtime if you try to apply `r` you'll have `StackOverflowError` (or similar error).

```
lazy val r: Int => Int = f _ compose r 

def r(n: Int): Int = f(r(n))
```

Comment: I am expecting it to run with no StackOverflow exception, some execution limitation logic need to be put in place.

Comment: Oh... I see, its just down to second function to stop execution some how.

Comment: @Pavel this "some how" is throwing an exception, which is far away from functional programming (exception is a side-effect) - so I believe it's better to reimplement your solution in a more appropriate way (even if it's imperative). Your options here: mutual recursion (with trampolines), iterators, streams

Comment: Question was specifically related to function composition, I am happy with the answer.